# Converting .jp2 to .jpg but the code is running infinitely

Tags: python, infinite

I am trying to convert .jp2 files in my folder to .jpg format.

```
import os
import pyvips

#Assigned directory
directory = 'D:\Anaconda\data'
 
# iterate over files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    #print(filename)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        #Used pyvis for conversion
        image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(f)
        #storing only the name of the file, removing extension
        fp = filename[:-4]
        image.write_to_file(fp + "j.jpg")
```

When I am running this code, it's running infinitely without giving any errors. I stopped it manually. What should I do to convert all my .jp2 files in the folder to .jpg?

Comment: Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-using-python/

Comment: How do you know that it is running infinitely and not just until it has processed all files in the directory? What is it doing after the last file?

Comment: Where is the test for `filename.endswith('.jp2')` ? Does it copy all files currently? What did the debug-prints say?

Comment: @hc_dev I have already put all the .jp2 files in the separate folder and then I am converting those .jp2 into .jpg. The code I have uploaded is just the conversion code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import pyvips

# assign directory
directory = 'D:\Anaconda\data\\'
target_path_img = 'D:\Anaconda\dataset_image\\'
 
# iterate over files in
# that directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    #print(directory)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        #print(f)
        image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(f)
        fat = filename[:-4]
        #print(fat)
        image.write_to_file(target_path_img + fat + "_img.jpg")
```

I know it's pretty lame but can be improved. Moreover, it's giving me the correct result.

Comment: What did you change? What was the problem before? How did you solve it?

Comment: Everything is the same in the code except I changed the last line. Added the correct target directory and voila !! @mkrieger1